# MySQL Trigger after insert and add timestamp when data changed

Tags: mysql, perl

This is my perl sample code and what i needed is add a timestamp into columns when data changed(updated).

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $datestring = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",localtime;
my $dbh = DBI->("dbi:mysql:dbname=perldb","root","111111",{RaiseError=>1})
    or die DBI::errstr();

my $mac1='mac1';
my $ip1='ip1';
my $mac2='mac2';
my $ip2='ip2';

$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test1");
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE Test1(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,IP TEXT,MAC TEXT,TIME DATETIME,PrevTime DATETIME) ENGINE=InnoDB");
$dbh->do("CREATE Trigger trigger1 AFTER INSERT ON Test1
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF OLD.MAC!=NEW.MAC
        THEN SET NEW.TIME='$datestring';
        END IF;
        END;")

$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Test1(IP,MAC) VALUES('$ip1','$mac1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=VALUE(IP)");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Test1(IP,MAC) VALUES('$ip2','$mac2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=VALUE(IP)");

$dbh->disconnect();
```

The goal I want to reach is run this code once then modify $mac1 to 'mac3'.
So that it will trigger SET timestamp because the data was changed.
Also SET old one timestamp to PrevTIME, but OLD for INSERT.

Result I need maybe like this:
    
    `+----+------+------+---------------------+----------+
    | Id | IP   | MAC  | TIME                | PrevTime |
    +----+------+------+---------------------+----------+
    |  1 | ip1  | mac1 | 2015-03-03 12:34:56 | NULL     |
    |  2 | ip2  | mac2 | 2015-03-03 12:34:56 | NULL     |
    +----+------+------+---------------------+----------+`

Then
    
    `+----+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | Id | IP   | MAC  | TIME                | PrevTime            |
    +----+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |  1 | ip1  | mac3 | 2015-03-03 12:40:00 | 2015-03-03 12:34:56 |
    |  2 | ip2  | mac2 | 2015-03-03 12:34:56 | NULL                |
    +----+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+`

Anyidea? Please help me figure out,THANK YOU.

-------------------------------SOLUTION---------------------------------------

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $datestring = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",localtime;
my $dbh = DBI->("dbi:mysql:dbname=perldb","root","111111",{RaiseError=>1})
    or die DBI::errstr();

my $mac1='mac1';
my $ip1='ip1';
my $mac2='mac2';
my $ip2='ip2';

$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test1(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,IP TEXT,MAC TEXT,TIME DATETIME,PrevTime DATETIME,UNIQUE(IP)) ENGINE=InnoDB");
$dbh->do("CREATE Trigger trigger1 BEFORE INSERT ON Test1
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        SET NEW.TIME='$datestring';
        END;")
$dbh->do("CREATE Trigger trigger2 BEFORE UPDATE ON Test1
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF OLD.MAC <> NEW.MAC
        THEN
        SET NEW.PrevTIME=OLD.TIME;
        SET NEW.TIME='$datestring';
        END IF;
        END;")

$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Test1(IP,MAC) VALUES('$ip1','$mac1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=VALUE(MAC)");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Test1(IP,MAC) VALUES('$ip2','$mac2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=VALUE(MAC)");

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need 2 triggers one `before insert` and one `before update`. The before insert will set the TIME to `now()`, while the before update will check the old and new values of mac and set the `PrevTime` to old TIME and TIME to `now()`

Here are the triggers, you can have them in your code

```
delimiter //
create trigger trigger1 before insert on Test1
for each row
begin
  set new.TIME = now();
end ; //


delimiter //
create trigger trigger2 before update on Test1
for each row
begin
  if old.MAC <> new.MAC then
    set new.PrevTime = old.TIME ;
    set new.TIME = now();
  end if;
end ;//
```

Comment: but `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` seems don't count as update, so the trigger of update won't work.

Comment: and trigger of insert works again. the result of table will be both two TIME modified. PrevTIME still both NULL.

Comment: Thats correct on duplicate update wount count as update command and its insert instead.

Comment: then is there any solution to replace `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and still same function?

Comment: Well that will be fairly difficult one thing could be done to remove the on-duplicate from the table definition and handle everything from the trigger or may be use trigger signal when duplicate happens.

Comment: what about using `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Test1 WHERE MAC='$mac1')` ,will it work? I tried and show up syntax error...

Comment: No the query is not correct you can use something as `insert into test1 (IP,MAC) select * from (select 'ip input','mac input') as t where not exists ( select 1 from test1 where IP = 'ip input' ) limit 1`;

Comment: hey! I found that [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) said that it's possible be `UPDATE` statement if use `UNIQUE KEY`,is it true?

Comment: Yes unique will force you to enter unique value for the defined column

Comment: then why I added `UNIQUE KEY` to MAC but still doing 'delete-insert' to table? weird...

Comment: unique key is a constraint to the table to ensure that you do not have duplicate records based on a key.

Comment: I understand what you said, but it mentioned that to prevent unique key duplicate and it will update so that duplicate won't happen. and please help me tried the example code I post.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are *event* specific.

You are using an `INSERT` and hence `AFTER` or `BEFORE` Trigger works defined for `INSERT` events.

You actually need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.
Add a similar trigger for `BEFORE TRIGGER`

**Example**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bu_on_Test BEFORE UPDATE ON Test1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF OLD.MAC <> NEW.MAC THEN
       SET NEW.TIME='$datestring';
   END IF;
END;
```

But note that Triggers won't take dynamic input parameters like `'$datestring'`.
If such a value is set in your scripting language, that is for lifetime of trigger definition and is not going to change during its execution.